# End of record when writing to /dev/null

Tags: fortran, gfortran, openmpi, dev-null

In our numerical software I encountered a strange bug after upgrading our cluster.
It namely is:

```
At line 501 of file /home/weser/code/neci/src/fcimc_helper.F90 (unit = 6, file = '/dev/null')
Fortran runtime error: End of record
```

In this line there is a `print *,`  statement that prints to stdout.

In our program the STDOUT of all non-root MPI processes is closed and reopened to write to `/dev/null`.
(Except in Debug mode, then the STDOUT of every non-root MPI process is redirected to a separate file.)

I tried to create a minimal example for this problem which looks like this:

```
  program stdout_to_dev_null
      use iso_fortran_env, only: stdout => output_unit
      use mpi_f08  ! also works with plain mpi
      implicit none(type, external)
  
      integer :: rank, n_procs, ierror
      integer, parameter :: root = 0 
  
      call MPI_INIT(ierror)
      call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, n_procs, ierror)
      call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierror)
  
      if (rank /= root) then
          close(stdout, status="keep")
          open(stdout, file="/dev/null", recl=8192)
      end if
  
      write(stdout, *) 'Size is ', n_procs
      write(stdout, *) 'node', rank, ': Hello world'
  
      block
          integer :: i
          character(:), allocatable :: large_string
          allocate(character(len=5000) :: large_string)
  
          do i = 1, len(large_string)
              large_string(i : i) = 'A' 
          end do
  
          write(stdout, *) large_string
      end block
  
  
      call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
  
  end program
```

The problem is that this minimal example works completely as expected, when run manually using `mpirun`, but also when actually sent to the cluster like other heavy calculations.

Now I have three questions: Do I have undefined behaviour in such code, when closing and reopening STDOUT and I am simply lucky in the minimal example? How can there be an End of Record in `/dev/null`? How can I properly fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with MPI and also nothing to do with the difference in cluster.¹
It is problematic code, that fails with `gfortran` but works under `ifort` by pure luck.

If the file is opened with a fixed record length (`recl=...`) a write statement must not exceed this length, even if the output goes to `/dev/null`.
The fix is simply to not open with a fixed record length and omit the `recl=...` argument.

Apparently the runtime library of `ifort` is more permissive and even works if the byte length of the written object is larger than the record length specified in the `open` statement.

In the following example the last `write` statement fails under `gfortran`.

```
program stdout_to_dev_null
    use iso_fortran_env, only: stdout => output_unit
    implicit none(type, external)

    integer, parameter :: rec_length = 10

    write(stdout, *) 'asdf'

    close(stdout, status="keep")

    open(stdout, file="/dev/null")
    block
        integer :: i
        character(:), allocatable :: large_string

        allocate(character(len=rec_length - 1) :: large_string)

        do i = 1, len(large_string)
            large_string(i : i) = 'A'
        end do

        write(stdout, *) large_string

        deallocate(large_string)
        allocate(character(len=rec_length + 1) :: large_string)

        do i = 1, len(large_string)
            large_string(i : i) = 'A'
        end do

        write(stdout, *) large_string
    end block
    close(stdout, status="keep")

    open(stdout, file="/dev/null", recl=rec_length)
    block
        integer :: i
        character(:), allocatable :: large_string

        allocate(character(len=rec_length - 1) :: large_string)

        do i = 1, len(large_string)
            large_string(i : i) = 'A'
        end do

        write(stdout, *) large_string

        deallocate(large_string)
        allocate(character(len=rec_length + 1) :: large_string)

        do i = 1, len(large_string)
            large_string(i : i) = 'A'
        end do

        ! The following statement fails
        write(stdout, *) large_string
    end block
    close(stdout, status="keep")

end program
```

---

¹ The relevant difference between the old and the new cluster for this problem is that we use `gfortran + OpenMPI` on the new one and `ifort + IntelMPI` on the old one.